# How to change dynamically a href reference

Tags: javascript, html

I have a navbar, like this:

```
<a href="#head" class="navbar-icon iconactive" id="startIcon">
```

I dynamically create:

```
$(".content").append("<div id="1"><section class='section' id='head'>.....);
$(".content").append("<div id="2"><section class='section' id='head'>.....);
```

`head` is the `id` of the section that is currently displayed (I have 2 divs).
I want to dynamically change the navbar `a href` depending on the `div` that is currently displayed.

Comment: Yes, but what is the goal? Do you want to toggle content with a single link?

Comment: I swipe the content of the page using divs. The problem is that divs contain different sections that can be visualized clicking on navbar icons. The navbar is only one for all divs but the content of divs sections are different so I should chage a href link in dipendence on the div (swipe content) displayed.

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with same id.  I am not quite following what you are trying to do here.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: I know that I can't have multiple elements. I would like to do something like this:      $(".content").append("<div id="1"><section class='section' id='head1'>.....);
$(".content").append("<div id="2"><section class='section' id='head2'>.....);         and then change a href link on #head1 or #head2 in dipendence on what div is displayed (swiped)

Comment: Has this been resolved for you? Did any of the answers answer your question? If not let us know so we can help more. Otherwise, please mark the most helpful answer as "accepted". Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.toggle();`

```js
$(function() {
    $('.toggle').on('click', function() {
       $('.content1').toggle();
       $('.content2').toggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.content2 {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="toggle">Toggle</a>
<div class="page">
    <div class="content1">:)</div>
    <div class="content2">:(</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fmkaj81p/

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the best way to handle this is using

http://api.jquery.com/index/

I understood you establish the first div as visible, right? Then just when your event (might be a scroll or keyboard input or click ) to hide div and show other happens just add to your logic the a href update as something like

```
$("a").attr("href",$("newDiv").attr("id"));
```

Also go inside the next link to get your own working depending on your jQuery version

http://api.jquery.com/attr/